# From PHP to HTML for Facebook web application

Tags: php, html, facebook

I have currently created a Facebook web application with php. There is a share button at the end of the application and I would like for the share to include variables I collected from a previous form, i.e:

```
 <meta property="og:url" content= <? php print "'" . "http://URL&q1=" . $name . "&q2=" . $type . "'"; ?> />
```

However, it seems like these PHP variables do not transfer over to Facebook so the thumbnail image and description of the app does not appear.

Is there away to save the contents of the page as FULL html and pass that along? 
My question is how can I save this file locally as a html as if I am looking at the page source through a browser.

Comment: What does `echo "name: $name, type: $type";` output?

Comment: the url is "http://URL&q1=fluffy&q2=dog"

Comment: The content's value should be encapsulated in quotes. Your `q1` should be preceded with a `?`, not an `&`.

Comment: fixed it variables still not passing through. I guess my question is how can I save this file locally as a html as if I am looking at the page source through a browser.

Answer (score 0):

1. All the attributes have to be within quotes.
2. Your domain isn't in the `content` attribute.

---

```
<meta property="og:url"
    content="<?php echo "http://www.domain.com?website=$name&q2=$type"; ?>"
/>
```